# How do I remove a Google user with access to my site?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Users can go to [account.google.com](http://accounts.google.com/) and revoke access from my site. How can I accomplish the same thing?

I have a site that uses Google authentication. The site, however, does not have a sign up process. New users are added by the site administrators. This is accomplished by simply adding their email to a list. This works fine in most cases. If a user comes to the site they are requested to authenticate with Google. I get their email if it is on the list I let them in. If it is not I tell them that they are not authorized to use the site.

If the user has multiple Google accounts logged in to their browser everything works fine. If the user has only one account signed in, and that is an authorized account all is well too. The next time they go to the site they are allowed in without authentication. Which is really cool.

However, if the one account they have signed in with on their browser is not authorized they are immideatly taken to the "You are not authorized" page. They are not given the opportunity to sign in with some other account.

If I could revoke the permission they granted to the site in Google (for unauthorized users), the next time they come to the site it would ask them to sign in again **and give them the option of signing in with another account**. Authorized accounts are typically work accounts. I am afraid that because the sign in process is so quick and easy, if someone accidentally signs in with their personal account on their phone they won't get a second chance to correct the error.

Comment: there is a revoke endpoint but you will need either the access token or the refresh token from said users authentication flow

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo, that is the correct answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by [Revoking the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke). Thanks @DalmTo

> In some cases a user may wish to revoke access given to an application. A user can revoke access by visiting Account Settings. It is also possible for an application to programmatically revoke the access given to it. Programmatic revocation is important in instances where a user unsubscribes or removes an application. In other words, part of the removal process can include an API request to ensure the permissions granted to the application are removed.